# Eclipse does not recognize static web content under src/main/resources/static

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring boot web project. I have an index.html file under `src/main/webapp`, and a .js file under `src/main/resources/static/js`.

Eclipse is complaining on the `<script></script>` inclusion inside the index.html file: Undefined Javascript file.
The above is also the case for css files under `src/main/resources/static/css`.

In addition, I'm using wro to generate unified angularjs-bootstrap js and css files, which are generated under `target\generated-resources\static` and Eclipse cannot find them either.

Is there any way to configure Eclipse to include the above directories?

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources ? if it that please create an issue with your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The javascript and css files must be placed under src/main/webapp so that they go in the correct location when the final WAR is built.  Files placed under src/main/resources will be placed in the java class path of the WAR when it is deployed (i.e., under the classes directory of the WAR). You should update your project by placing css/javascript files under src/main/webapp. wro can also be configured to work properly with eclipse see: [CSS and JS minification using Eclipse, Maven and WRO4J](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/01/17/css-and-js-minification-using-eclipse-maven-and-wro4j)

Comment: +1 for a workaround solution, dropping the files into src/main/webapp works, but the Eclipse Spring boot plugin creates the src/main/resources/static directory so that you can put static content there. I expect some magic to happen which will take care of HTML validation.